# Prove Inequality $(a + b + c)d - (ab+ bc +ca) \leq 0 $ if $(ab + bc + ca)d - 3abc \leq 0$ .

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The following variables are real positive numbers, $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that, the following inequality is satisfied 
$(ab + bc + ca)d  - 3abc \leq 0$. Prove the following,
$(a + b + c)d - (ab+ bc +ca) \leq 0 $.

I tried the following approach,
Taking Harmonic mean of ab,bc,ca which gives $3\frac{abc}{a+b+c} \leq \frac{abc}{d}$. I obtained the following inequality from it $3d−(a+b+c) \leq 0$. After this I am stuck, do not have any idea on proceeding.

Comment: I tried taking Harmonic mean of $ab, bc, ca$ which gives $3 \frac{abc}{a+b+c} \leq \frac{3abc}{d}$. I obtained the following inequality from it $3d - (a+b+c) \leq 0$. After this I am stuck, do not have any idea on proceeding.

Comment: Can you add that to your question body with an edit?

Answer (score 6):

Basically you're being asked to show that $d \leq {3abc \over ab + bc + ac}$ implies $d \leq {ab + bc + ac \over a + b + c}$. This is equivalent to showing that for all positive $a,b,c$ you have
$${3abc \over ab + bc + ac} \leq {ab + bc + ac \over a + b + c}$$
Let $a = {1 \over x}$, $b = {1 \over y}$, and $c = {1 \over z}$. Then what you are trying to show is that for all $x,y,z > 0$ you have
$${3 \over x + y + z} \leq {x + y + z \over xy + yz + xz}$$
This can be rewritten as 
$$3xy + 3yz + 3xz \leq (x + y + z)^2$$
This expands to
$$0 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - xz$$
Or equivalently 
$$0 \leq {1 \over 2} (x - y)^2 + {1 \over 2}(x - z)^2 + {1 \over 2}(y - z)^2$$
This trivially holds since the right-hand side is nonnegative, so we're done.

Comment: Thanks, I want to clarify the first part of the answer. So the first inequality, $ d \leq \frac{3abc}{ab+bc+ca}$ implies $d \leq \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}$. From this, your inference is that $\frac{3abc}{ab+bc+ca}$ is a tighter bound on $d$ than $\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}$. Hence, $ \frac{3abc}{ab+bc+ca} \leq \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}$?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to look at it. Or just use transitivity with $d \leq {3abc \over ab + bc + ca} \leq {ab + bc + ac \over a + b + c}$ implying $d \leq  {ab + bc + ac \over a + b + c}$.